# pandas, How to apply a function to all columns using another as parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not too expert with pandas and hence there's one thing I cannot do.

I have a dataframe with several columns: he first is a int, the others are floats.

I want to apply a function to all columns using the first one as a parameter for the function.
Example:

```
  A    B    C
  4   0.3  0.5
  7   0.2  0.6
```

I have a function which I want to apply to columns B and C, whose result depends on the value of A for that row.

The only way I can think of is a sort of zip between first column and the others, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: depends on the function, there might be smarter ways depending on what you really want to achieve

Comment: For example: `df.drop('A', axis=1).apply(lambda x: x*df['A'])`

Comment: you need to add ```axis=1``` to apply: ```df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A']+x['B'] if x['A'] > x['B'] else None , axis=1)```